# Having issues to make the data value in centre in pie chat using high charts

Tags: highcharts

Please check this link http://www.highcharts.com/demo/3d-pie.

I am using this 3d charts and facing to issues to place chrome, i.e, safari like data values in **centre** each of the colour place.  How can i do this ?

any idea ?  how can place data values in centre ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust the `distance` property of the `datalabels` options, however in 3d mode this isn't always successful as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/69Mxj/

But if you sacrifice the 3D angle you can get them in the middle : http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/99SFQ/ (without any 3d options)
http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/69Mxj/1/ (with 3d `alpha:10`)

```
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            depth: 35,
            dataLabels: {
                distance: -30,
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....Already tried with distance: -30 but not getting the values in centre..  let i check with alpha... Need a correct solution for placing in centre as accurate.... :(

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it looks like a bug with the distance parameter, so I reported it to our developers [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/3259)